# boundedness of pdf of summation of sub-Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I came accross the following counter-intuitive problem.

Given $0 < \lambda < 1$, consider $\eta_i \sim N(0,1)$ to be a sequence of i.i.d standard normal distributions. Then, $\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda^i \eta_i \sim N(0, \frac{1 - \lambda^N}{1 - \lambda})$, as we have a sum of normal distribution. In particular, as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the pdf of the random variable obtained from the summation is bounded (by the pdf of the normal distribution it converges to).

However, if we relax the assumption and only take $\eta$ to be sub-Gaussian, I can not tell if $\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda^i \eta_i$ has bounded pdf or not. In particular, if we take $\eta$ to be uniform on $[-1,1]$ (bounded random variable are sub-Gaussian). Then, the essential supremum of the resulting pdf seems to be
$$\sup_{y} \int_{y_1} \dots \int_{y_{N-1}}\varphi(y)\prod_{i=1}^{N} \varphi\left(\frac{y}{\lambda^{i}} - y_i\right)/\lambda^{i} dy_1\dots dy_{N-1}$$
where $\varphi$ is the pdf of $\eta$.
I have a hard time trying to found an upper bound for this as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

I have also tried to look into this by using characteristic function but still with little success. As we may be able to show the CF of $\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda^i \eta_i$ is bounded, but that does not imply the essential supremum of the pdf is also bounded.

My question is, is it still true that the essential supremum of the pdf of $\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda^i \eta_i$ is bounded when $\eta_i$'s are sub-Gassian?